# Compare and combine strings to get duplicates

Tags: c#, string, linq

I will try to describe my question in the best way I can.

I have a list with X strings ("NOTION", "CATION", "COIN", "NOON").

I am trying to compare them and find the most times each character (letter) was used, use that to get the number of that character, arrange them in alphabetical order, and create a string.

So the result string should be: "ACINNOOT"

Hope is clear what I am describing.

EDIT

So far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.Length; i++)
{
     string letter = word.Substring(i, 1);

     tempDuplicatedLetterList.Add(letter);               
}

// Which letters are repeated and how many times
var duplicatedQuery = tempDuplicatedLetterList.GroupBy(x => x)
                                      .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                      .Select(y => new { Element = y.Key, Counter = y.Count() })
                                      .ToList();
```

Comment: "Hope is clear what I am describing." It is. What is unclear is this: what did you try already to solve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the most times each character was used, use that to get the number of that character you need, arrange them in alphabetical order, and create a string. So ("CHEESE", "GOAT", "MUFFIN") would produce "ACEEEFFGHIMNOS", right? Can you show your effort to solve this?

Comment: Why is the result `"ACINNOOT"`, and not `"NOACINOT"` for example?

Comment: why is N and O twice in your word? the rules for the word construction are not really clear yet

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just sort them alphabetically so its "ACINNOOT".

Comment: I count 6 times N in your words, and many O's as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere exactly, I only need 1A, 1C, 1I, 2N, 2O, 1T and not all of them. I need the maximum number each letter is used and then create one word with those letters.

Comment: @John Yes exactly this is what I am trying to achieve. I edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came to this, although I think there might be a cleaner way to do it:

```
var characterSets = new string[] { "NOTION", "CATION", "COIN", "NOON" }
       .SelectMany(c => c.GroupBy(cc => cc)) // create character groups for each string, and flatten the groups
       .GroupBy(c => c.Key) // group the groups
       .OrderBy(cg => cg.Key) // order by the character (alphabetical)
       .Select(cg => new string(cg.Key, cg.Max(v => v.Count()))) // create a string for each group, using the maximum count for that character
       .ToArray(); // make an array

var result = string.Concat(characterSets);
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I need to pass in a list instead but this should work. Thank you.

Comment: The only other way I could come up with to do it in a semi-LINQy way was to use `.Aggregate`, but I don't feel that it's much of an improvement over this.

Comment: Just tested it and it works. Thank you very much for this.